# WSO2 calling a sequence from another one

Tags: wso2, sequence, wso2-enterprise-integrator

I want to call a sequence in another one when the http return code is 401

I tried to handle that in this way but I could not call other one.

```
<filter regex=".*401" source="get-property('axis2', 'HTTP_SC')" xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd">
    <then>
        <call-template target="conf:sequences/otherSequence.xml"></call-template>
    </then>
</filter>
```

WSO2 version 6.4.0

Thanks for any idea!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<sequence key="conf:sequences/bsi.otherSequence.xml"></sequence>
```

Comment: Can I call a sequence from another project altogether in my current project? I have a use case wherein I am dividing my monolithic project into multiple smaller projects. As part of this, I want to place all the common shared sequences in a single project which will be imported into all the other projects.

Comment: You can deploy all common sequence files to `<APIM_HOME>/repository/deployment/server/synapse-configs/default/sequences/` directory and refer to those from your API specific sequences as mentioned above.